# DLL File for windows 7 64bit

Tags: sqlite, windows-7, 64-bit

I'm porting my Windows XP application (wrote with C#) to Windows 7 application.
Now I'm using sqlite3.dll on my XP App (32bit) and I would download sqlite3.dll for 64bit machine.
For my purpose I've moved sqlite3.dll on my /bin folder and, obviously, when I try to start my app on windows 7 I receive an error.
So, where I download this file?

Please, help me...

Edit: I've downloaded sqlite3 http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The SQLite website only has the 32-bit .dll, to get a 64-bit one you'll have to download and compile the source yourself.

Since you're using C#, an easier way is to use System.Data.SQLite ( http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/ ). They have a 64-bit download available, which is SQLite itself and their ADO.NET provider combined into one .dll. It's the easiest way to use SQLite on Windows with C# I think.

Update: New download URL is http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Comment: Using System.Data.SQLite would be easier if the application wasn't already written. I think just compiling to 64 bit is the way to go for Cecco, since he's porting.

Answer (score 4):

bin/x64 directory contains 64-bit NATIVE DLL, named System.Data.SQLite.dll which is SQLITE3.dll compiled for AMD64/X86_64 platforms.
The url is:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/files/SQLite%20for%20ADO.NET%202.0/1.0.66.0/
(IF it was you`re looking for).

Comment: This worked for me. (Extracted this DLL, renamed it, and put it in the directory of the Win64 binary).

Answer (score 1):

1. Download SQLite-1.0.66.0-setup.exe from
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/files/SQLite%20for%20ADO.NET%202.0/1.0.66.0/
2. Run this executable will create a folder under C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLite.NET
3. Pick the System.Data.SQLite.DLL from bin/x64 and renamed it to sqlite3.dll
   -- and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, since your app was already written, you won't want to rewrite it.
You can simply recompile your .NET project targeting to 32 bit.

Right click your *project*-> *properties* -> *build* -> *platform target : x86*

64 bit app can only run on 64 machine while 32 bit app can run on both.