# Unhandled exception on opening sqlite database in windows x64

Tags: c#, sqlite, 64-bit

I have created a project in Visual Studio 2008 that uses sqlite in 32-bit Operation System.
Then I made a setup project with installa ware 15 for a 64-bit Operation System.

I added sqlite dll(s) in beside of `.exe` file and when I create 32-bit setup all thing work properly.

But when I create 64-bit setup project, the installation in a 64-bit Operation System (like Windows 7, 8) the program will not run and it throws:

> Unhandled exception .... unable to open database.....

How to can I solve it?

Comment: Given it is first time install issue, ensure that all dependencies required by your application are present in the installation. I would compare the setup with that from your x64 debug environment first.

Comment: in installation folder my files is: .exe file and sql.mdf ,.... sqlite.dll,sqlite.net.dll,sqlite3.dll                                                                      in vs2008, target platform is 'any cpu'

Comment: Check [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18163354/4519059) And [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3839669/4519059), I think those can help ;).

Comment: tnks for your attention.